# Output canvas data along with BG image into another canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have an image(with id `picc`).
I then have a canvas (say `c1`), into which I use the `drawImage()` function to draw `picc` into it.

I then `getImageData()` of `c1`, do some pixel changes in it (like making some of the pixels as transparent), and put this data into another canvas (say `c2`) which also has a background image to it in CSS.

How can I make it such that another canvas (say `c3`) has the output from the 2nd canvas including the background image generated in it?

This is my current code (note that there may be some cross-origin issues in rendering this canvas, that I'm not sure of):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
img = document.getElementById("picc");
c1 = document.getElementById("c1");
ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
c2 = document.getElementById("c2");
ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
c1.width= c2.width= img.width; 
c1.height= c2.height= img.height; 

ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
let frame = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, c1.width, c1.height);

let l = frame.data.length / 4;
  
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        let r = frame.data[i * 4 + 0];
        let g = frame.data[i * 4 + 1];
        let b = frame.data[i * 4 + 2];
        if (g >= 242 && r >= 244 && b <= 243)
              frame.data[i * 4 + 3] = 0
}

ctx2.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
});
```

```css
#c2 {
        background-image: url("https://cdn.britannica.com/84/4284-050-16C7E8C2/Photograph-Jupiter-range-Voyager-1-cloud-bands-February-1-1979.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;     background-size: cover;
      }
```

```html
    <div>
      <img src='https://previews.123rf.com/images/rabbybsl/rabbybsl2008/rabbybsl200800018/153141202-holi-color-background-on-white-background.jpg' id="picc" width="360" height="640"/>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
      <canvas id="c2"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to actually draw the background image onto canvas

Comment: I suspect you may not quite understand what you are getting in frame.data. To make a pixel transparent you need to zeroize its 4th byte, not just any old byte. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

Comment: A fuller description can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: There is quite a lot missing from the code you have given which you must already have. Please make the code you have given into a runnable snippet with an actual image - we need to know how you set the dimensions of canvas and img. Please also show some real setting of the transpareny of a few (say at least 3) pixels so we have something to work on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth, you are right. I have made changes now to my question to make it more clear.